# How to customize kendo editor tool arrangement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I am using the KendoUI html editor, in inline mode. It works fine, but I have found some problems with the arranging of toolbar items. Namely:

- I have added custom tools to the toolbar. They are not correctly 'tagged' with the k-group-start, or k-group-end classes, and thus thir edges, and margins are not correct.
- I can't influence where the toolbar puts in the 'k-group-break' item (what makes a linebreak on the toolbar).

I have tried to modify these in the selection changed event (according to the demo page, that gets fired every time I click into the edited area), but the kendo built-in logic overwrites my changes after that.

Has anyone encountered this problem? What could be a good solution? I am pretty lost, since I haven't found anything on this topic in the kendo documentation, so some hack might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a tool ".Separator()" in your tools list and it will create an empty "li" ..

```
<li class="k-separator k-group-start"></li>
```

you can than style this element to create the spaces, I have made this li as a block element so it pushed everything which follows down.

Hope this helps.

Cheers